# Same Python command works on one computer but doesn't on another in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I have an issue with running this command in Maya 2020.4:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.lookThru('CAMERA:sh*_Vcam')
```

I'm trying to look through a camera, and Maya gives me this error when I try to run it:

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 3: Too few arguments given.
```

I asked a friend, who ran it for me on a different PC with the same Maya version, and it worked.
What am I missing?

Comment: What Python version are you working with?

Comment: is Python 2.7.11 within Maya 2020.4

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: here is the full error message:

import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.lookThru('CAMERA:sh*_Vcam')

# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 3: Too few arguments given. #

Answer (score 0):

That error seems to appear when it can't find a camera.

Do a `cmds.ls('CAMERA:sh*_Vcam')` and see if it finds anything, if not then that's your issue.

```
mc.lookThru('persp') # works

mc.lookThru('invalid') # RuntimeError

# Quick function if you'd like to avoid the error
def lookThru(cam):
    try:
        mc.lookThru(cam)
    except RuntimeError:
        mc.warning('No camera found matching {!r}.'.format(cam))
```